# Можно ли изменить перо в turtle как хочешь?

Tags: python, turtle, shape

Можно ли изменить перо в turtle, не используя shape ?
Мне для этого вопроса код не нужен, но правила такие, что нужен код:

```
from turtle import *

bgcolor("cyan")
setup(450, 450)

done()
```

Comment: Чтобы сделать свою форму пера используйте Shape("compound") https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#compound-shapes.

Comment: Если хотите свою картинку, используйте turtle.register_shape('example.gif'), см https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713235/using-images-as-turtle-shape#:~:text=You%20can%20register%20a%20.gif